# regex to find a big chunk of text between delimiters

Tags: regex

I need some help getting the text marked in the red rectangle with the help of a regex:
https://preview.ibb.co/bK1cay/regex.png

I tried to use the following delimiters:
In the beginning:
3.1
Finding 1
Risco:

And in the end:
Recomendação

By delimiters I'm meaning that these are the only strings that may be used to detect the text in the red square, as these delimiters are the only ones that won't change. All the other strings will change.

Here is the full text: https://regex101.com/r/A2tnaq/1

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which programming language?

Answer (score 1):

It's surely inefficient, but one solution is:

`(?s)3\.1[^\n]*?\n[^\n]*?Finding 1.*?Risco:\s*\S*\s*(.*?)\s*?Recomendação`

The capturing group matches your desired text.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Yes, there is a match earlier in the document, nevertheless I'd like only the mentioned one to be detected.

Comment: @blucah I've updated the regex to hopefully resolve the problem. It relies on "Finding 1" being on the very next line after "3.1". Is this OK?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the difference between the text in green and the text in blue --> https://regex101.com/r/A2tnaq/2  Using the regex in my software (Uipath), I get the blue text as a result. And I would like to have only the text in green.

Comment: @blucah So the bit in green is the first capturing group. I'm not familiar with UiPath but usually you just need to specify that you want the first group, instead of the whole match. [This forum thread](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-pull-out-regex-groups-in-uipath-seperately/12043) seems to be based around a similar problem (the last post might help you?).

Comment: @blucah If you're using a programming language within that software, the solution to getting that one group may be language specific. Let me know if you need further help on this.

Comment: Well, in Uipath you simply insert the regular expression you provided and there is no way to select the first group or whole match... Isn’t there any other regex expression one can use that does not have any division into first group/whole match?

Comment: @blucah I'm not aware of any way to do this without utilising capturing groups. I struggle to understand how an application that is designed to work with regular expressions would prevent you from using such a simple construct. This is almost delving into an entirely different question now, about how to use it within the software. There must be some way of using the result from your regex to enumerate over the results or access a returned object somehow. From what I can find online, it looks like you can use programming languages within the software, can you confirm that you are not using one?

Comment: @blucah Usually, you would get something like a `Matches` object which you can do something similar to `string desiredText = matches[0].Groups(1).Value` with.

Comment: Watkings, unfortunately I'm unable to make this work.
Are you sure that it's not possible to create a regex WITHOUT first group/whole match? That is, a regular expression that caches the green selection here: https://regex101.com/r/A2tnaq/2, but only with blue color?

Comment: @blucah Like I said, I'm not aware of any way to do this without utilising capturing groups. You may wish to consider posting this as a new question under the [uipath] tag where you're more likely to get some help on getting the groups from the regular expression that you now have. You haven't said much about how the software works here so I can't really help you, but in a new question you can show an image of what you are working with etc. and I'd be happy to at least take a look.